# Find an equation to transform $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6, 7, 8\}$ to $\{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there a way to transform $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6, 7, 8\}$ to $\{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1\}$ by applying a single function?
That is, transform $1$ to $8$, $2$ to $7$, $3$ to $6$ etc.

Comment: i find this but i dont know what is the n into the equation http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100275/transformation-matrix-for-matrix-indices-to-cartesian-coordinates

Comment: Guy wants an interpolating polynomial like $9-x$, I guess.

Comment: If you want to learn a general method to find any function of this sort have a look at this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f(x) = 9 - x$

$f(1) = 9 - 1= 8$

$f(3) = 9 - 3 = 6$

etc.